# Creation of a column with the information from another column

Tags: python, pandas

Probably a naive question, but I am not able to get the logical hold on the problem. I have a dataset which looks like the same -

```
       Date_1  Count  Value
0   18/8/2018    220     10
1   24/8/2018    231     14
2   29/8/2018    272      9
3   20/7/2018     83      5
4   13/7/2018     53      5
5   24/7/2018    120     10
6   17/8/2018    196      1
7   26/7/2018    118      1
8   22/8/2018    236     11
9   19/7/2018     74      4
10  26/7/2018    118     12
11  10/8/2018    168     16
12  29/8/2018    272      2
13   5/7/2018     18    148
14  24/8/2018    231     11
15   3/8/2018    154     13
16  20/8/2018    245      1
17  31/8/2018    320      6
18  26/8/2018    287      8
19  10/7/2018     39     24
20   2/8/2018    143     12
21   2/8/2018    143     12
```

This is just a snippet of the csv that I have. Date corresponds to a particular date, count corresponds to the number of times the date is being repeated and Value is a information for each date. I want to create a new column Value_2 which would have the particular logic :

for a particular date it would be 3500-Value. So for example

for date 2/8/2018 as you can see 2 dates in the example the output should be -

```
Date_1           Count    Value     Value_2
2/8/2018         143      12     3488(3500-12)

2/8/2018         143      12     3476(3488-12)
```

and so on..

The dataset has a total of 20000 entries.

I am able to achieve the total for a particular date using the `groupby` function in python, but not able to achieve this for a particular instance of a date.

Thanks

Comment: From the context I assume you are trying to achieve the requested calculation in `pandas`. So IMO you should add this tag to your post and delete `excel`, as there is no Excel related aspect in this question.

Comment: @SpghttCd I took the liberty of adding `pandas` ;)

Comment: @SpghttCd Thanks for the advice, I removed the same. New to stackoverflow and still learning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df['Value_2'] = 3500 - df.groupby('Date_1').Value.cumsum()

#        Date_1  Count  Value  Value_2
# 0   18/8/2018    220     10     3490
# 1   24/8/2018    231     14     3486
# 2   29/8/2018    272      9     3491
# 3   20/7/2018     83      5     3495
# 4   13/7/2018     53      5     3495
# 5   24/7/2018    120     10     3490
# 6   17/8/2018    196      1     3499
# 7   26/7/2018    118      1     3499
# 8   22/8/2018    236     11     3489
# 9   19/7/2018     74      4     3496
# 10  26/7/2018    118     12     3487
# 11  10/8/2018    168     16     3484
# 12  29/8/2018    272      2     3489
# 13   5/7/2018     18    148     3352
# 14  24/8/2018    231     11     3475
# 15   3/8/2018    154     13     3487
# 16  20/8/2018    245      1     3499
# 17  31/8/2018    320      6     3494
# 18  26/8/2018    287      8     3492
# 19  10/7/2018     39     24     3476
# 20   2/8/2018    143     12     3488
# 21   2/8/2018    143     12     3476
```